# How to get data from checkbuttons to a list in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, class, react-props

I am a beginner with React Native, so I need help with following:
I am programming an App, where you can choose between two radio button groups. To every radio button should belong data (key and value pairs, in categories). If choose two options and afterwards press the butto "Create my plan" it should randomly choose some entries of the key value kategories and create a flatlist from it.
My problem is, that I dont know how I can pass data bewteen two classes or if there is an other way to realize what I picture.

Please do not be put off by the amount of code, if you copy it and paste it into an empty project, it works immediately and you will understand my question.

I am very grateful for your help.

Here is my Code:

```
import React, { Component, useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, Dimensions,  Button, View, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Animated } from 'react-native';
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { RadioButton } from 'react-native-paper';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';



//Ein StackNavigator-Objekt wird erzeugt
const Stack = createStackNavigator();


  

class Auswahl extends React.Component {

  state = {
    value1: 'first',
    value2: 'first',
    value3: 'first',
    checked: 'agnostic'
  };

  render() {


    return (
     
      <View style={{alignItems:"center", flex:1, flexDirection:'column' }}>
      <View style={{position:'absolute', alignItems:"center", flex:1, flexDirection:'column'}}>
      <Text style={{ marginTop:50, marginBottom:10 }}>Auf welchem Niveau praktizierst du?</Text>
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', marginBottom: 20}}>
        <RadioButton.Group 
          onValueChange={value1 => this.setState({ value1 })}
          value={this.state.value1}>
         
            <Text>Anfgänger</Text>
            <RadioButton.Android value="first" />
            <Text>Geübt</Text>
            <RadioButton.Android value="second" />
            <Text>Eingeschränkt</Text>
            <RadioButton.Android value="third" />
            </RadioButton.Group>  
           
    
      <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>Möchtest du einen Fokus setzten?</Text>
      <RadioButton.Group 
      onValueChange={value2 => this.setState({ value2 })}
      value={this.state.value2}>
         
            <Text>Dehnung</Text>
            <RadioButton.Android value="first" />
            <Text>Hüftöfner</Text>
            <RadioButton.Android value="second" />
            <Text>Energie</Text>
            <RadioButton.Android value="third" />
         
        </RadioButton.Group>

        <Button style={{margin:10, padding:10}} title="Erstelle meinen Plan" onPress={() => 
        this.props.navigation.navigate('UebungenAnzeigen') }/>
        </View>
        <View/>
        </View>
        </View>
   
    );
  }
}

class UebungenAnzeigen extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
   this.state = {
    
    data:[
      {
      
        "name": "Herabschauender Hund",
        "kategorie":"Basic",
        "nummer" : "0",
        "erklaerung": "Steißbein zur Decke | Rücken gerade | Kopf in Verlängerung der Wirbelsäule",
        "photo": "",
        "dauer": 30
    },
       
    {
        "name": "Katze",
        "nummer" : "2",
        "erklaerung": "Steißbein zur Decke | Rücken gerade | Kopf in Verlängerung der Wirbelsäule",
        "photo": "",
        "dauer": 20
    },
  
    ]
  }

  }
  
  render() {

    
    
    function Item({ item }) {
      const [shouldShow, setShouldShow] = useState(true);
     
      return (
  
      <View style={styles.container}>
    
        {shouldShow ? (
          
         null
          
        ) :   
        <View style={stylesUebungAnzeigen.uebung}>
        <Text>Details</Text>
        <Text style={{marginTop: 20 }}>{item.name}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop: 100, color:'green'}} onPress= {() => setShouldShow(!shouldShow)}>Zurück zur Übersicht</TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
         }
        
    
        <View style={stylesUebungAnzeigen.listItem}>
          <Image source={item.photo}  style={{width:90, height:60, borderRadius:10}} />
        <View style={{alignItems:"center",flex:1}}>
          <Text style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Text>{item.dauer}</Text>
        </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShouldShow(!shouldShow)} style={{height:50,width:50, 
          justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"} }>
          <Text style={{color:"green", fontWeight:"bold"}}>Hilfestellung?</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          </View>
       
      );
    } 

    return ( 
      
      <View>
      <View style={stylesUebungAnzeigen.container2}>
          <FlatList style={{flex:1}}
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item= {item}/>}
          keyExtractor={item => item}
          />  
      </View>
      </View>
  
      );

    }
  }
  


const stylesUebungAnzeigen = StyleSheet.create ({

  buttons: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf:"center",
    height: 10,
    width: 30
    
 }, 

 uebung:{
  fex:1,
  alignSelf:"center",
  justifyContent:"center",
  height: 911,
  width: 318,
  borderColor:'grey',
  backgroundColor: 'white'

 },

 text:{
   flex:1,
   justifyContent: 'center'
 },

  container2: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F7F7F7',
    marginTop:60
  },

  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    marginTop: 10

  },

 

  listItem:{
    margin:10,
    padding:10,
    backgroundColor:"#FFF",
    width:"80%",
    flex:1,
    alignSelf:"center",
    flexDirection:"row",
    borderRadius:2
  },


});

// geht nicht umzubennen nochmal gucken
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },

  container:{
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
  },

  group: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    },

  SeparatorLine :{
   
  backgroundColor : '#fff',
  width: 1,
  height: 40
   
  },


    elementsContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#ecf5fd',
 
  }

});




export default class Willkommen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
            name="Auswahl"
            component={Auswahl}
          />
      
      <Stack.Screen
            name="UebungenAnzeigen"
            component={UebungenAnzeigen}
          />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}


registerRootComponent(Willkommen);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand the question. Because its just if else to check which one is selected (according to your schema).
How you will pass values from one screen to another is as follows.

```
<Button style={{margin:10, padding:10}} title="Erstelle meinen Plan" onPress={() => 
    this.props.navigation.navigate('UebungenAnzeigen',{
   data : {value1, value2 ,...etc}}) }/>
```

And on next screen you can receive that data using following code.

```
let data = props.route.params?.data;
console.log(data.value1, data.value2)
```

Comment: Thanks al lot, I will try it soon and let you know if it worked out for me.

Comment: Do I have to replace value1, value2 with names of the keys in the key value pairs of the state? In which section on the next screen do I have to place the let data = props.route... and the console log? In the return statement?

Comment: Its json you use whatever names you want. Doesn't matter what are the names of states.
e.g 
 this.props.navigation.navigate('UebungenAnzeigen',{
   data : {FirstFilter: value1, Filter2:value2 ,...etc}})

You can follow further.
Thankyou.

Comment: If I so the second command on the second screen it says: Props is not defined. Its not working for me.

Comment: For class you need add "this." before props.